# Is Hyperparameter Optimization A Discrete Or Continuous Problem?

Tags: tuning

I'm currently learning AI/machine-learning with Python and Scikit-learn. Not having a strong background in math, I'm confused on a certain point.

Say I want to tune the parameters of a machine learning model in order to reduce its error rate. For an example, let's use a [support vector machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support-vector_machine).

Some of the [several parameters it accepts](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) are floats, others are integers or booleans, yet others are strings.

Would searching over the space of parameter values in order to reduce the error rate be considered a discrete, or continuous optimization problem?

Comment: i believe the technical term is "mixed" optimization.